# AWS Device Farm with Appium - How can I force the app the be opened in full screen?

Tags: amazon-web-services, appium, appium-android, aws-device-farm

I'm running a test in device farm using Appium on Galaxy S8, but the test is being stuck on the first screen of the app for a very long time and I came to the conclusion that it happens due to the reason that the app is being opened not in a full-screen mode (in Galaxy S7 the test runs and ends).

Is there any way, programmatically or other, to make the app in Device Farm open in full screen?

Comment: Could you please provide the appium server logs and video?

Comment: Have u tried with 'Maximize Window ' API in Appium ,you can refer here https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/commands/web/window/maximize-window/

Comment: @pankajmishra this is a web API and not for apps

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as **full/ minimized screen** in terms of **Appium API**.
All the apps on both iOS and Android **starts in full screen**.

However Android Nougat introduced split screen mode, when you have 2 apps opened at the same time. Make a screenshot or [captured screenshots or video to confirm](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/faq/)

If its really your case (I still doubt), then try to close 2nd app with Touch Action (just swipe it right)